# How can I define a Python Callable type for annotating a decorator, where the decorator uses some parameters and absorbs the rest in **kw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing

I'm looking to annotate a decorator in Python 3.11, where

1. the decorated functions use keyword-only parameters,
2. the decorated functions share a small number of keyword-only parameters, say `a` & `b`,
3. the decorator's inner function uses those parameters, and
4. each function may specify the number of additional keyword parameters (which, besides forwarding them along, the decorator does not care about).

How can I annotate this in a way that will satisfy mypy 0.991?

I expected the following would work:

```
import functools
from typing import Protocol


class MyCallable(Protocol):

    async def __call__(self, *, a: int, b: str, **kw):
        ...


def deco(f: MyCallable) -> MyCallable:
    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(*, a: int, b: str, **kw):
        return await f(a=a, b=b, **kw)
    return wrapper


@deco
async def func1(*, a: int, b: str):
    """
    error: Argument 1 to "deco" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'a'), NamedArg(str, 'b')], Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]"; expected "MyCallable"  [arg-type]
    """


@deco
async def func2(*, a: int, b: str, c: int):
    """
    error: Argument 1 to "deco" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'a'), NamedArg(str, 'b'), NamedArg(int, 'c')], Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]"; expected "MyCallable"  [arg-type]
    """


@deco3
async def func3(*, a: int, b: str, d: int, e: int):
    """
    error: Argument 1 to "deco" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'a'), NamedArg(str, 'b'), NamedArg(int, 'd'), NamedArg(int, 'e')], Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]"; expected "MyCallable"  [arg-type]
    """
```

but all three cases give errors (see docstrings).

Adding `**kw` to `func1` does the trick there:

```
@deco
async def func1(*, a: int, b: str, **kw):
    ...
```

The same move fails (expectedly) for `func2`:

> error: Argument 1 to "deco" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'a'), NamedArg(str, 'b'), NamedArg(int, 'c'), KwArg(Any)], Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]"; expected "MyCallable"  [arg-type]

I suspect the issue is due to my protocol "saying" it allows any number of keyword parameters but my funcs not actually accepting that. However, since `deco` neither injects nor removes parameters, I naively assumed mypy would see that a+b+kw perfectly overlaps the function signature and we'd be good to go.

---

The following works in the general case:

```
MyCallable: TypeAlias = Callable[..., T]
```

but I'm not happy with the amount of information this discards. I.e., since the decorator relies on `a` & `b`, I want to be warned during the static analysis pass if the decorated function is missing either of those.

---

Is this possible?

If not, what's the best alternative? (I have a preference for leaving the `func` signatures as they are, with no `**kw`, if possible.)

Comment: I think this is a use-case for `typing.ParamSpec`, rather than a `Protocol`.

Comment: You could use `ParamSpec`, but you would not be able to define the constraint of having named parameters `a` and `b`. Unfortunately `Concatenate` only works with positional arguments. And even so, it is unclear how to define the restriction of not having _any_ positional arguments with a ParamSpec. I feel like the so called "callback protocol" approach should work, but I cannot figure it out. The frustrating part here is that the error messages by `mypy` are very unhelpful, when something _doesn't_ match a callback protocol.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg yes I'm pretty sure this is a gap in the current functionality of `ParamSpec` & callback `Protocol`